Javascript form validation hindering data insertion to PHP
I created form validation in Javascript and its working but the data can’t be inserted to the backend PHP. They can only insert data when they comment out e.preventDefault(), so my client side validation doesn’t work but there's work and the data is inserted. what could be the issue?
this is the javascript code, i also tried ajax and it logged form data as an object so its working. but they were not able to use it.
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
let isValid = true;

    if (firstNameInput.value.trim() === '' || firstNameInput.value.trim().length < 3) {
        displayError(firstNameInput, 'Please enter a valid first name!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(firstNameInput);
    }

    if (lastNameInput.value.trim() === '' || lastNameInput.value.length < 3) {
        displayError(lastNameInput, 'Please enter a valid last name!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(lastNameInput);
    }

    if (!emailIsValid(emailInput.value)) {
        displayError(emailInput, 'Please enter a valid email!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(emailInput);
    }

    if (numberInput.value === '' || numberInput.value.length < 11){
        displayError(numberInput, 'Please enter a valid mobile number!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(numberInput);
    }

    if (passwordInput.value === '' || passwordInput.value.length < 8) {
        displayError(passwordInput, 'Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(passwordInput);
    }

    if (countrySelect.value === 'Country*') {
        displayError(countrySelect, 'Please select a country!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(countrySelect);
    }

    if (companyNameInput.value === '') {
        displayError(companyNameInput, 'Please enter your workplace!');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        hideError(companyNameInput);
    }

if (!isValid) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form is not submitted (validation failed)");
} else {
    signupForm.submit();
    console.log("Form is submitted (validation passed)");
}


console.log(isValid)});


function emailIsValid(email) {
    return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);
}

function displayError(element, message) {
    const errorParent = element.closest('.input-parent');
    const errorMsg = errorParent.querySelector('.error');

    errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
    errorMsg.textContent = message;
    element.classList.add('is-invalid');
}


function hideError(element) {
    const successParent = element.closest('.input-parent');
    const successMsg = successParent.querySelector('.success');
    const errorParent = element.closest('.input-parent');
    const errorMsg = errorParent.querySelector('.error');

    successMsg.textContent = '';
    successMsg.style.display = 'block';
    errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    element.classList.remove('is-invalid');
}

any help would be appreciated

"Doesn't work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "doesn't work" in code, like a mechanic can't fix a car that "doesn't work" without any other information about the problem. How isn't it working? What debugging have you done? What exactly happens when you run this? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. See also What do you mean "It doesn't work"?

If the problem is in your JavaScript validation code then you should debug the JavaScript code, using your browser's Developer Tools. It will have nothing to do with PHP or MySQL (since the code never reaches them, when you have this issue), so I'm going to remove those tags. See also [ask], and What are tags, and how should I use them?

There’s no errors when i log it and it passes validation. But when the backend try, the data is not inserted in their database and they don’t have errors either

So are you saying that the signupForm.submit(); is executed successfully, and the form still posts back after validation? Or not? Your comment doesn't say specifically what happens at that point.

P.S. really your event.preventDefault(); needs to be at the beginning of the function, otherwise there's a slight danger the form will simply post back anyway, without having time to run all the JS code. You always want to prevent the standard submit action, no matter what. Then, if validation succeeds you can submit the form with the .submit() command as your code is trying to do now. If it fails then of course you display the errors. But you shouldn't wait to get the result of the validation before preventing the default submit.

So really it should be: signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => { event.preventDefault(); let isValid = true; ... and then later on if (!isValid) {     console.log("Form is not submitted (validation failed)"); } else {  console.log("Form is submitted (validation passed)"); signupForm.submit();  } (note that the "form is submitted" console log should come before you submit the form, otherwise it might not be executed. If you have the "preserve log" option in your developer tools enabled, you'll then be able to see it, if that line is executed)

I intiay added the event.preventDefault(); at the beginning of the code as you suggested, then changed it at the if statement thinking it might be the issue. So the issue is i enter the data, when validation is successful i receive form is submitted in the console, if failed i get false and not submitted. But there code doesn’t insert the data in their database as long as event.preventdefault is present in my code and their validation works at that phase and data is inserted to the database

So did you check that the form is actually submitted by the .submit() command? Use the code with event.preventDefault() at the start, as I showed. Open the Network tool open in your browser's Developer Tools. Then fill in your data to be valid, and hit Submit in your form. If the form is submitted, then in the Network tool you should see a new request going to your PHP script. Do you see that? You can click on that request to inspect it and see what form data was sent in the payload, and what response PHP sent back.

@ADyson I've never heard of that requirement for event.preventDefault(), and it makes no sense. The browser doesn't perform the default event processing until the listener returns, and preventDefault() prevents it. JavaScript is single-threaded, nothing else is running while the listener runs, so it won't post while this is happening.

Instead of doing validation in JS, why not do it in HTML? Add attributes like required, minlength, and maxlength. Use type="email" for the email instead of your own validation function.

@Barmar ok. I know JS itself is single-threaded, but didn't know that would prevent the browser from following its normal form submit process while the JS code is running. Every example I've ever seen has preventDefault() as the first line of the listener, and so I assumed that was so it would prevent the submit action immediately.

@ADyson The times when this is required is when the validation function is asynchronous (e.g. it uses AJAX to validate something). Or when you're using AJAX submission instead of normal form submission. But calling form.submit() isn't always equivalent, e.g. it will not send the submit button.

@Barmar good point. That could be the source of the OP's issue potentially - depends what the server-side code is checking when it receives the form data. And thanks for the clarification on preventDefault(). You can do this stuff for years and years and still not know something fundamental.

@MennaRihan As Barmar points out this could be an issue with how you process the form data in PHP when it's received, because form.submit() may send slightly different data (e.g. it won't send values for any named buttons in the form, unlike when those buttons are clicked directly to submit). Can you show the PHP code responsible for receiving this form submission?

Use the Network tab of DevTools to see what values are actually being sent to the server. That way you'll know whether to debug this on the client or server side.

Use the build-in form validation instead of creating your own. The form will only submit if all the required (the required attribute) form fields are valid. There is a number of ways that you can validate some value. Here I used the pattern attribute that takes a regular expression as a value to validate against.


document.forms.signup.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let label = e.target.closest('label');
  label.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.signup.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let label = e.target.closest('label');
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    label.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
.error {
  font-size: smaller;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.invalid~.error {
  visibility: visible;
}
<form name="signup" action="/signup" method="POST">
  <label>First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" required></label>
  <div class="error">Please enter a your first name</div>
  <label>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" required></label>
  <div class="error">Please enter a your last name</div>
  <label>Email: <input type="email" name="email" required></label>
  <div class="error">Please enter a valid email</div>
  <label>Mobile: <input type="text" name="number"
    pattern="[0-9]{6,8}" required></label>
  <div class="error">Please enter a valid mobile number (6-8 didets)</div>
  <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}" required></label>
  <div class="error">Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.</div>
  <label>Country: <select name="country" required>
<option value="">Select a country</option>
<option value="1">Country 1</option>
<option value="2">Country 2</option>
</select></label>
  <div class="error">Please select a country</div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



